# Swedish rounding in invoices

Tags: rounding, invoice

I'm designing a invoice feature for my web app, and i'm introduced to issue of rounding up numbers for certain countries like Sweden, Switzerland, New Zealand.

The thing that confuses me is that i'm not sure if is should round up the total invoice amount or total amount of every invoice line.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a question you should be asking your client.  I would have thought it's per item given they are discrete items however it would depend on what you're selling... e.g. if it was various pieces of metal and each one was rounded I'd feel a little miffed.  If it's T-Shirts I'd expect it to be rounded... only your client can answer though.  If the client is you, you can choose!

Comment: I'm from NZ, rounding is applied to the total amount, not each line item.